# Read and Write to USB Device on Raspberry Pi 3 using Java

Tags: java, linux, usb, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I'm using Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi 3. I'm learning how to code in Java (SE runtime version 1.8.0_65), and I need to communicate raw data with a USB connected Bill Acceptor. According to the manufacturer's documentation, the USB unit mimics a serial-type interface. When I plug the device in, it appears in `/dev/serial/by-id`. I wrote C code 20+ years ago using modems on SCO Unix setups. If memory serves, I basically treated the modems `/dev/ttyxx` as a file for reading and writing. I wrote a C++ program 10+ years ago on Windows XP using a similar Bill Acceptor unit (same manufacturer and model) connected to a serial port instead of USB. The documentation shows both USB and serial units use the same data strings for input and output, so I know the SendString data should be correct for triggering a valid response.  However, I'm not getting a reply from the unit, so I'm guessing I'm not connecting properly to it.

Here is the code...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try
    {
        System.out.println("*****************************");
        System.out.println("*****  Starting Program *****");
        System.out.println("*****************************");
        String strUsbDeviceDir = "/dev/serial/by-id";
        File myUsbDeviceDir = new File(strUsbDeviceDir);
        if(myUsbDeviceDir.exists())
        {
           String[] myUsbDevices = myUsbDeviceDir.list();
           for(int i=0; i<myUsbDevices.length; i++)
           {
               if(myUsbDevices[i].contains("EBDS_over_USB"))
               {
                   System.out.println("Connecting to " + myUsbDevices[i]);
                   funcBillAcceptor(strUsbDeviceDir + "/" + myUsbDevices[i]);
               }
               else
               {
                   System.out.println("Not using " + myUsbDevices[i]);
               }
           }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.err.println(ex.toString());
    }
}

public static void funcBillAcceptor(String strBillAcceptor)
{
    boolean bOddCount = false;
    byte[] SendString = new byte[8];
    byte[] RecvString = new byte[10];
    byte CheckDigit;
    int iSendStringCount, iRecvStringCount, iRecvEmptyCount;

    try
    {
        File fBillAcceptor = new File(strBillAcceptor);
        if(!fBillAcceptor.canRead())
        {
            System.out.println("No Read Permission for " + strBillAcceptor);
            return;
        }
        if(!fBillAcceptor.canWrite())
        {
            System.out.println("No Write Permission for " + strBillAcceptor);
            return;
        }

        RandomAccessFile rafBillAcceptor = new RandomAccessFile(strBillAcceptor, "rwd");
        if(rafBillAcceptor != null)
        {
            System.out.println("Successfully opened " + strBillAcceptor);
        }

        while(fBillAcceptor.exists())
        {
            SendString[0] = (byte) 0x02; //STX
            SendString[1] = (byte) 0x08;
            if(bOddCount)
            {
                SendString[2] = (byte) 0x10;
                bOddCount = false;
            }
            else
            {
                SendString[2] = (byte) 0x11;
                bOddCount = true;
            }
            SendString[3] = (byte) 0x1F;
            SendString[4] = (byte) 0x0C;
            SendString[5] = (byte) 0x00;
            SendString[6] = (byte) 0x03; //ETX

            //CheckDigit skips STX (byte 0) with byte 1 as seed/initial value
            //To calculate the check digit, start with next byte (2)
            CheckDigit = SendString[1];
            iSendStringCount = 2;
            while(SendString[iSendStringCount] != 0x03)
            {
                CheckDigit = (byte) (SendString[iSendStringCount]^CheckDigit); //XOR current CheckDigit value with next byte
                iSendStringCount++;
            }
            iSendStringCount++; //advance one more so we don't overwrite ETX
            SendString[iSendStringCount] = (byte) CheckDigit;

            try
            {
                rafBillAcceptor.write(SendString);
                System.out.println("Sent: " + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(SendString));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.err.println("Write exception: " + ex.toString());
            }

            System.out.println("Reading...");
            iRecvStringCount = iRecvEmptyCount = 0;
            try
            {
                do
                {
                    iRecvStringCount = rafBillAcceptor.read(RecvString);
                    System.out.println("Read " + iRecvStringCount + " bytes.");
                    if(iRecvStringCount < 0)
                    {
                        iRecvEmptyCount++;
                        Thread.sleep(5);
                    }
                } while (iRecvStringCount < 0 && iRecvEmptyCount < 100);
                if(iRecvStringCount > 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("Received: " + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(RecvString));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.err.println("Read exception: " + ex.toString());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.err.println(ex.toString());
    }
}
```

Here is the output I'm getting...

```
*****************************
*****  Starting Program *****
*****************************
Connecting to usb-Silicon_Labs_Series_2000_Bill_Acceptor__EBDS_over_USB__46580120748-if00-port0
Successfully opened /dev/serial/by-id/usb-Silicon_Labs_Series_2000_Bill_Acceptor__EBDS_over_USB__46580120748-if00-port0
Sent: 0208111F0C00030A
Reading...
```

Am I missing something obvious, or just going about this all wrong?  Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Remove the try-catch or re-throw exceptions or print error messages to System.out instead of err, may be they are getting lost. Also, this creates a file `new RandomAccessFile(strBillAcceptor, "rwd");` but that device is not a regular file AND is already created, may be that's a problem.

Comment: I changed all the System.err.println commands to System.out.println, and the output didn't change.  I chose the "rwd" option based on [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).  My take away from the documentation was the command wouldn't try to create a file since I confirm it exists, and I can both read from and write to the file/device before I try to create the handle to the file/device using RandomAccessFile.  Is there a different command that is better suited for use with a device versus a file?

Comment: I haven't experience on that area, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully communicate with the Bill Acceptor from a Raspberry Pi 3 (running Raspbian) using the [RXTXComm library](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). When communicating with the device from an old Windows XP computer using a 9-pin serial/RS232 harness, I had to use 9600/7/E/1. If I don't use those values for setSerialPortParams (in my sample code), I'm not able to correctly send/receive data. So, you need to know what the device is expecting in order to use this approach with other "serial" hardware connected via USB. Below is code with the basic functionality. I started with one of the sample programs that come with the RXTXComm library and built out from there. Since this is a sample program, I haven't yet added logic to verify the checksum digit for data coming from the device.

You may notice at the bottom of the code that I'm able to determine the /dev/ttyUSBx using the canonical name of the device that I pull from the `/dev/serial/by-id` directory/folder. It finds the correct device name regardless of which USB port the unit is plugged in to or what order the USB devices get initialized by the system. I have a card dispenser that is also a USB serial device, so I was able to test and confirm this functionality.

```
public TwoWaySerialComm()
{
    super();
}

static boolean bReadyToSend = false;

void connect ( String portName ) throws Exception
{
    CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName);
    if ( portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned() )
    {
        System.out.println("Error: " + portName + " is currently in use.");
    }
    else
    {
        CommPort commPort = portIdentifier.open(this.getClass().getName(), 2000);

        if ( commPort instanceof SerialPort )
        {
            SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort) commPort;
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_7, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_EVEN);

            InputStream in = serialPort.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = serialPort.getOutputStream();

            // Thread handling logic
            // https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue056.html
            Thread readThread = new Thread(new SerialReader(in));
            readThread.start();
            Thread writeThread = new Thread(new SerialWriter(out));
            writeThread.start();

            // Running threads for 10 seconds then stopping to ensure threads are shutting down
            long threadCurrTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long threadStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while( (threadCurrTime - threadStartTime) < 10000)
            {
                try 
                {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex)
                {
                    Logger.getLogger(TwoWaySerialComm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex); 
                }
                threadCurrTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }

            if(writeThread.isAlive())
            {
                //System.out.println("Sending interrupt to SerialWriter thread...");
                writeThread.interrupt();
                writeThread.join();
                //System.out.println("SerialWriter thread is shut down.");
            }
            //else
            //{
            //    System.out.println("SerialWriter thread is already shut down.");
            //}

            if(readThread.isAlive())
            {
                //System.out.println("Sending interrupt to SerialReader thread...");
                readThread.interrupt();
                readThread.join();
                //System.out.println("SerialReader thread is shut down.");
            }
            //else
            //{
            //    System.out.println("SerialReader thread is already shut down.");
            //}

            commPort.close();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error: " + portName + " is not recognized as a valid serial device.");
        }
    }     
}

/* SerialReader thread logic */
public static class SerialReader implements Runnable 
{
    InputStream in;
    boolean bShuttingDown = false;

    public SerialReader ( InputStream in )
    {
        this.in = in;
    }

    public void run ()
    {
        byte[] RecvString = new byte[12];
        String strResponse;
        int len = -1;
        try
        {
            while (!bShuttingDown)
            {
                len = this.in.read(RecvString);

                if( len > -1 )
                {
                    strResponse = "";
                    if(RecvString[0] == 0x02 && RecvString[9] == 0x03)
                    {
                        if(RecvString[3] == 0x00 && RecvString[4] == 0x00 && RecvString[5] == 0x00 && RecvString[6] == 0x00)
                        {
                            strResponse = "Device not ready.";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //-- RecvString[3]------------------
                            if(RecvString[3] == 0x01)
                                strResponse = " - Idling";
                            else
                            if(RecvString[3] == 0x02)
                                strResponse = " - Accepting";
                            else
                            if(RecvString[3] == 0x04)
                            {
                                strResponse = " - Escrowed";

                                if(RecvString[5] == 0x08)
                                    strResponse += " $1";
                                else
                                if(RecvString[5] == 0x10)
                                    strResponse += " $2";
                                else
                                if(RecvString[5] == 0x18)
                                    strResponse += " $5";
                                else
                                if(RecvString[5] == 0x20)
                                    strResponse += " $10";
                                else
                                if(RecvString[5] == 0x28)
                                    strResponse += " $20";
                                else
                                    strResponse += " unrecognized bill inserted";
                            }
                            else
                            if(RecvString[3] == 0x08)
                                strResponse = " - Stacking";
                            else
                            if(RecvString[3] == 0x10)
                                strResponse = " - Stacked";
                            else
                            if(RecvString[3] == 0x11)
                                strResponse = " - Returning";
                            else
                            if(RecvString[3] == 0x12)
                                strResponse = " - Returned";

                            //-- RecvString[4]------------------
                            if(RecvString[4] == 0x01)
                                strResponse += " - Cheated";
                            else
                            if(RecvString[4] == 0x02)
                                strResponse += " - Rejected";
                            else
                            if(RecvString[4] == 0x04)
                                strResponse += " - Jammed";
                            else
                            if(RecvString[4] == 0x08)
                                strResponse += " - Bill Stacker Full";
                            else
                            if(RecvString[4] == 0x10)
                                strResponse += " - Removable Cassette Installed";
                            else
                            if(RecvString[4] == 0x11)
                                strResponse += " - Reserved";
                            else
                            if(RecvString[4] == 0x12)
                                strResponse += " - Calibration mode";

                            //-- RecvString[5]------------------
                            if(RecvString[5] == 0x01)
                                strResponse += " - Power Up Reset";
                            else
                            if(RecvString[5] == 0x02)
                                strResponse += " - Invalid Command";
                            else
                            if(RecvString[5] == 0x04)
                                strResponse += " - Non-recoverable fault";
                        }
                        if(!strResponse.contains("Idling"))
                            System.out.println("Recv: " + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(RecvString) + strResponse);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Recv (invalid): " + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(RecvString));
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(100); // need this delay before we send next polling message, otherwise the data doesn't come in correctly
                        bReadyToSend = true;
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException ex)
                    {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        //System.out.println("Shut down SerialReader thread.");
                        bShuttingDown = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch ( IOException ex )
        {
            System.out.println("Recv exception: " + ex.toString());
        }            
    }
}

/* SerialWriter thread logic */
public static class SerialWriter implements Runnable 
{
    OutputStream out;
    long lastSendTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1001;
    long currSendTime;
    byte[] SendString = new byte[8];
    byte CheckDigit;
    int iSendStringCount;
    boolean bOddCount = true;
    boolean bShuttingDown = false;

    public SerialWriter ( OutputStream out )
    {
        this.out = out;
    }

    public void run ()
    {
        while(!bShuttingDown)
        {
            currSendTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if(currSendTime - lastSendTime > 1000) // if it's been more than a second, send query string
                bReadyToSend = true;

            if(bReadyToSend)
            {
                SendString[0] = (byte) 0x02; //STX
                SendString[1] = (byte) 0x08;
                if(bOddCount)
                {
                    SendString[2] = (byte) 0x10;
                    bOddCount = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    SendString[2] = (byte) 0x11;
                    bOddCount = true;
                }
                SendString[3] = (byte) 0x7F;
                SendString[4] = (byte) 0x1C;
                SendString[5] = (byte) 0x00;
                SendString[6] = (byte) 0x03; //ETX

                //CheckDigit skips STX (byte 0) with byte 1 as seed/initial value
                //To calculate the check digit, start with next byte (2)
                CheckDigit = SendString[1];
                iSendStringCount = 2;
                while(SendString[iSendStringCount] != 0x03)
                {
                    CheckDigit = (byte) (SendString[iSendStringCount]^CheckDigit); //XOR current CheckDigit value with next byte
                    iSendStringCount++;
                }
                iSendStringCount++; //advance one more so we don't overwrite ETX
                SendString[iSendStringCount] = (byte) CheckDigit;

                try
                {
                    lastSendTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    this.out.write(SendString);
                    //System.out.println("Sent: " + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(SendString));
                }
                catch ( IOException ex )
                {
                    System.out.println("Send exception: " + ex.toString());
                }

                try
                { 
                    Thread.sleep(1); // this is hear simply to catch an external interrupt
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex)
                {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    //System.out.println("Shut down SerialWriter thread.");
                    bShuttingDown = true;
                    break;
                }
                bReadyToSend = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main ( String[] args )
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("*****************************");
        System.out.println("*****  Starting Program *****");
        System.out.println("*****************************");

        String strUsbDeviceDir = "/dev/serial/by-id";
        File myUsbDeviceDir = new File(strUsbDeviceDir);
        if(myUsbDeviceDir.exists())
        {
           String[] myUsbDevices = myUsbDeviceDir.list();
           for(int i=0; i<myUsbDevices.length; i++)
           {
               if(myUsbDevices[i].contains("EBDS_over_USB"))
               {
                   File tempFile = new File(strUsbDeviceDir + "/" + myUsbDevices[i]);
                   String usbCanonicalName = tempFile.getCanonicalFile().toString(); //gives me /dev/ttyUSBx where 'x' is the USB device number
                   System.out.println("Connecting to " + usbCanonicalName + " (" + myUsbDevices[i] + ")");
                   (new TwoWaySerialComm()).connect(usbCanonicalName);
               }
               else
               {
                   System.out.println("Not using " + myUsbDevices[i]);
               }
           }
        }
    }
    catch ( Exception ex )
    {
        System.out.println("Connect exception: " + ex.toString());
    }

    System.out.println("*****************************");
    System.out.println("***** Program Finished ******");
    System.out.println("*****************************");
}
```

Output when I put a $1 bill in (I'm developing/compiling from NetBeans IDE 8.2 on Windows 10 Pro and running using remote debugging on the RPi3. I'm guessing that's the source of the RXTX Version mismatch warning):

```
*****************************
*****  Starting Program *****
*****************************
Connecting to /dev/ttyUSB0 (usb-Silicon_Labs_Series_2000_Bill_Acceptor__EBDS_over_USB__46580120748-if00-port0)
Stable Library
=========================================
Native lib Version = RXTX-2.2pre2
Java lib Version   = RXTX-2.1-7
WARNING:  RXTX Version mismatch
    Jar version = RXTX-2.1-7
    native lib Version = RXTX-2.2pre2
Recv (invalid): 020000000000000000000000
Recv (invalid): 0B2001100800503603540000
Recv: 020B20041008005036035100 - Escrowed $1 - Removable Cassette Installed
*****************************
***** Program Finished ******
*****************************
```

I hope this description and sample code can help someone else.